# Create a function that uses a variable if it has already been initialized

Tags: javascript

My problem is this, there is a function out of the DOM that requires a variable that is initialized to load the DOM. The problem is even if the function is not invoked before loading the DOM, it creates this error: ReferenceError: variable is not defined. How to do so, preferably with an if statement, that as long as the variable is not initialized, the part that takes the variable is ignored?

```
<script>
function check(){
    if(num>100) alert('test');
    else alert('test2');
}
window.onload = function() {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    check();
}
</script>
```

I know that changing `function check()` with `function check(num)` and `check();` with `check(num);` working properly, but I do not like this solution, I would like to understand why my code does not work...

Comment: what is the code you are using?

Comment: declare the var num as global so that you will never get undefined errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of num is all wrong. Try this:

```
var num;
function check(){
    if(num>100) alert('test');
    else alert('test2');
}
window.onload = function() {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    check();
}
```

Comment: passing the variable instead of using a global would be better, 1) it would help keep the global space clean, and 2) check function would be more reusable.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I agree. But - OP stated that they don't want this. We have no way of knowing why not at the moment - perhaps there is some reason.

Answer (score 1):

`num` is only defined inside the `onload` function. You cannot access it in the `check` function unless you pass it as a parameter.

```
function check(num) {
    if( num>100) alert("Test");
    else alert("Test2");
}
window.onload = function() {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    check(num);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function (num) { 
    if( num>100) alert("Test");
    else alert("Test2");
})(Math.floor(Math.random()*11));
```

If you're not bothered about explicitly using the window.onload event, you could just use an anonymous function like above.